# Angular universal deployment in aws lightsail server

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, angular-universal

I have an Angular project and I've added Angular Universal to improve SEO. After running **ng build && ng run project-name:server**, I see two folders in the **dist** directory: **browser and server**.

Now I want to deploy my project to an **AWS Lightsail** server, but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide on deploying an Angular Universal project to an AWS server? I'm using Ubuntu on the server.

Thanks!

I want to deploy my project Angular universal project to an **AWS Lightsail** server